# Model Architecture / Design Pattern for Model Sharing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, architecture, software-design

I am building an app which uses twitter and facebook APIs.

I intend to store each tweet or status in it's own model, lets call the models `Tweet` and `Fb_Status`. I intend to create a more general model which contains the text content from both, lets call it `Statement`.

How should I architect this?

Acceptance Criteria would be something like:

- `Statement.all` returns records with two attribtues `message` and `word_count`. The `message` is inherited from `Tweet` or `Fb_Status`, whichever the statement represents, while `word_count` is a unique attribute of the `Statement` model.

Comment: tweets and status should be polymorphic I guess

Comment: Thanks @apneadiving, what I'm seeing in polymorphic associations is that its used in situations wherein `Posts` and `Pictures` have many `Comments`. In this case, a `Tweet` or `Fb_Status` has one `Statement` record associated with it.

Comment: yes you're right, I misread your question

Comment: +1 Sorry @apneadiving You were along the right lines. It seems that I'll have to use a polymorphic has_one association to accomplish MTI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have tagged this question with Ruby on Rails, I assume you would like to know, what Rails might have to offer in order to solve this.

Just with Ruby you can of course use class inheritance to get the desired behavior of your objects. On top of this Rails offer single table inheritance (STI), which maps all of your models that share some functionality to one database table. [Discussion of STI](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=3815)

STI has its limitations, which is why you might not want to use it. Instead you could map the different models to different database tables. This is not directly supported in Rails, but here is a [discussion of multiple table inheritance (MTI)](http://techspry.com/ruby_and_rails/multiple-table-inheritance-in-rails-3/)